# Change the fill or stroke colour of an SVG using a field value?

Tags: svg

Is it possible to change the fill or stroke colour of an SVG using a value pulled from a custom field?  For example:

```
{{ svg('@webroot/_dist/stat/link-arrow.svg')|attr({
    stroke: '{{ entry.myCustomFieldValue }}'
}) }}
```

I can only get it to partially work by using a class but unfortunately there are a number of SVGs on the page so we'd also need to change all the class names :/ - and it's ugly!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.3.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 37.9 20.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 37.9 20.1;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:{{entry.myCustomFieldValue }};stroke-width:2;}
</style>
<g transform="translate(0 0.526)">
    <line class="st0" x1="0" y1="9.8" x2="36.5" y2="9.8"/>
    <g transform="translate(31.688 1)">
        <path class="st0" d="M-1-1l2.8,4.5l3.6,5.8"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M-1,18l2.4-3.8l0,0l4-6.4"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are wrapping `{{ entry.myCustomFieldValue }}` in `'`, you are passing it as a string instead of its value, that's why you then see it *as is* in your result. Try:

```
{{ svg('@webroot/_dist/stat/link-arrow.svg')|attr({
    stroke: entry.myCustomFieldValue
}) }}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you never nest twig tags, meaning never put `{{ ... }}` inside of another `{{ ... }}`; the same applies to `{% ... %}` as well (or any mixture of the two).

Comment: Perfect thanks Oli and good tip Jalen Davenport!